# Are there any alternatives to Master pages for Asp.Net web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

As development of an ASP.NET Web Forms project rolls on, the code used in markup sometimes becomes repetitive.

Are master pages my only option to reuse that markup? Sometimes my Master page content won't refresh. Maybe it's time to replace it with something similar if it exists.

Comment: If you post the code regarding Master Page issue, we can gladly take a look at it.

Comment: @Win I don't want you to solve that problem, because it's very complex and I have posted some questions regarding it and nobody tried even to comment on it. I just want to know if they are any alternatives to master pages. But thank you very much for the good intentions, I really appreciate!

Comment: Not sure what's the point in closing this question as *Too Broad*. I don't see it a broad question rather a straight forward question. Voted to Re-Open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a `UserControl` but that would be wired alternative cause in that case you will have to create separate usercontrol for header/footer/menu item ... etc and have them registered on each page separately using a `@Register` page directive.

Comment: Is this similar to a partial view in asp mvc?

Comment: @meJustAndrew, yes it is same as partial view in MVC.

Comment: Thank you! There are some differences between a partial view, but it is what I need, and indeed it behaves like a partial view.